# How to implement a polymorphic function within member function in C++11?

Tags: c++, c++11, lambda, macros

I am using a framework written by others. The framework use some ugly macros.
Firstly, the framework use macro to declare and define class like below:

```
#define DECLARE_FUNC(_name, _params) \
class _name                          \
{                                    \
    static int execute();            \
    static int exec_func(_params* param);          \
}

#define DEFINE_FUNC(_name, _params)  \
int _name::execute()                 \
{                                    \
    _params p = get_from_global();   \
    return exec_func(&p)             \
}                                    \
int _name::exec_func(_param* param)
```

when using this framework what I have to do is:

```
DECLARE_FUNC(foo, database)

DEFINE_FUNC(foo, database)
{
    // write business logic here        
}
```

when write the business logic, I have to query information from different tables in database and do almost the same thing with query results. The pseudo codes are like following:

```
TypeA a = TABLE(t_TypeA)->Query();
if (a.is_valid()) {
   // do something with a here
   // some local variables are used here
}

TypeB b = TABLE(t_TypeB)->Query();
if (b.is_valid()) {
   // do something with b here
   // some local variables are used here
}
```

Obviously there are too many duplicate codes, which is bad. So my colleague use macro to remove the duplicate codes. I think polymorphic lambda should work in this case, but C++11 doesn't support polymorphic lambda.

My question: is there any other ways to remove the duplicate code without macro?

Update:
actually in source code "_params" is also a macro, it can expend to more parameters, I simplify it here. If expand the parameter macro and use polymorphic lambda, it looks like:

```
int ClassA::exec_func(Database database,
                      Date date,
                      Time time)
{
    // there are also some local variables, for example:
    long second = get_second(date, time);

    // polymorphic lambda version
    auto handle_table = [&](auto table_type) {
        // database, date, time and local variables will be used here
    }

    handle_table(TableA);
    handle_table(TableB);
    ...
    handle_table(TableX);
}
```

So Francis's solution may not work in this situation.

Comment: Would an abstract template base class that accepts a function pointer and database type as its template parameter work? This way your base class is abstract and can not be instantiated but the derived classes can be where they all share a similar interface. Any functions or methods that are unique to each derived class (database type) can be done by overriding the purely virtual functions using template specialization.

Comment: I'm honestly not sure what your question is, could you perhaps write a sketch how you could solve your problem using polymorphic lambdas? Also, which duplicate code would you like to avoid? Lastly, I'd seriously ask myself whether there is a good reason to use that framework at all, because the parts you show suggest some horribly convoluted design that could only be justified in the pre-variadic-template (or even pre-template) era.

Comment: @Ulrich To me this indeed looks like a scenario where templates would be an option. But Francis's solution would be even better, if possible. In general if i have function that does the same thing to part of the data of a class, I try to solve it by using inheritance.

Comment: wouldn't a `std::function` suffice?

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. I will add more codes to make it more clear later. @Ulrich I totally agree with you that the framework is horrible, and the design is worse. Yes, there is no good reason to use it, but that's the company's choice, I have to live with it.

Comment: @FrancisCugler, actually in source code "_params" is also a macro, it can expend to more parameters, I simplify it here.

Comment: Yeah it is tough converting old C to modern C++ when they are plagued with macros.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

lambdas can be written with class functors.

```
auto l = [&capture](auto param) {/*code*/};
```

becomes something like:

```
class MyFunctor
{
public:
    explicit MyFunctor(const capture_t& capture) : capture(capture) {}

    template <typename T>
    void operator () (T param) const { /* code */ }
private:
    const capture_t& capture; // or by value
};
```

and later

```
 auto l = MyFunctor(capture);
```

Comment: Thanks. But what capture_t is? could you give me some reference?

Comment: `capture_t` is the type of the variable `capture`.

Comment: How to capture more than one parameter in your implementation? because I want to use private data member too. The functor will have to capture too many parameters

Comment: @Neal: Use several members and add additional argument to the constructor.